# how to delete remained space after we make border none

Tags: html, css

I have a table where top and right borders are not required. So I made them border-top:none;border-right: none;. But as per my requirement, I will keep adding multiple tables one inside other. In that case, this top and right borders are keep adding up the size. Is there a way, where I can remove that space also ?
[image]

Comment: Adding Code would have helped a lot :(

Comment: Try adding some code lines so we may help accordingly.